# Csv file with columns with a lot of comma's itself

Tags: pandas, csv

I want to import a csv file with one of the columns of text what has itself a lot of commas (,)  double quotes (") and single quotes (') in it (actually all kinds of characters are there) as the data is IMDB reviews. Sometimes in even and odd quantities. So pandas sees these commas as column seperators.

What is the correct way of importing it with pandas like:

`pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=',', .....)`

Comment: Are fields that contain commas enclosed within quotes? If so, and then single quotes are used to represent quotes in those fields, I believe the `quoting` argument will allow you to parse it properly. Otherwise it's going to be a nightmare.

Comment: I checked, it really has any character you can imagine. Multiple double and single quotes.